# Passar valores de um form para outro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, macro

Caros

Tenho dois formulários A e B.

A = Tem o listview e exibe informações da base

B = Precisa receber as informações do form A e exibir. (Informações que não são exibas no form A)

Preciso fazer isso acontecer através do evento do listview_DblClick()

Comment: Falta um pouco de informação na sua dúvida mas veja se você consegue chamar o formulário A dentro do formulário B

Comment: Ex: TextBox1.Text =  FormA.ComboBox1.Text

Comment: E o que você tentou até o momento?

Comment: **-** Verifique como as Userforms estão declaradas, por exemplo: `Userform2.TextBox1 = Userform1.TexBox1.Value` . **-** E você precisará declarar variáveis globais. **-** As duas não são abertas simultaneamente, a não ser que seja utilizada `Vbmodeless`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caros

Conseguir fazer dessa forma:

No form B eu vou utilizar o seguinte código

```
formA.ListView1.SelectedItem.SubItems(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Caros não consegui acessar minha outra conta;

@Marco

Só estou tentando imaginar como irei fazer isso;

Estou testando armazenar o valor da coluna que preciso em variáveis (são muitas);

```
    For i = 2 To LinhaFinal
    Set Item = ListView1.ListItems.Add(Text:=Plan3.Cells(i, 1))
    Item.SubItems(1) = Plan3.Cells(i, 2)
    Item.SubItems(2) = Plan3.Cells(i, 3)
    Item.SubItems(3) = Plan3.Cells(i, 4)
    Item.SubItems(4) = Plan3.Cells(i, 5)
    Item.SubItems(5) = Plan3.Cells(i, 6)
    Item.SubItems(6) = Plan3.Cells(i, 7)
    Item.SubItems(7) = Plan3.Cells(i, 8)
    Item.SubItems(8) = Plan3.Cells(i, 69)
    Item.SubItems(9) = Plan3.Cells(i, 70)
    Item.SubItems(10) = Plan3.Cells(i, 71)
    Item.SubItems(11) = Plan3.Cells(i, 72)
    teste = Plan3.Cells(i, 67)

Next
```

Pretendo, passar essa variável "teste" para o outro form, pois lá eu tenho que exibir em um optionButton (mesma quantidade de variáveis).

Comment: Entre em contato com a SE através do link que segue e solicite "mesclar" as duas contas, assim você conseguirá obter controle do conteúdo da antiga https://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: @Articuno obrigado, já enviei a solicitação.

Comment: Acredito que não vou conseguir fazer essa parte dentro do FOR.

Pois não iria conseguir passar as informações para o outro form.